# Euclidean Distance functioning as Euclidean Direction in Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.4

I'm trying to call Euclidean Distance in an arcpy script within a toolbox. I've used arcpy.sa.EucDistance but the output raster is a Euclidean Direction raster. When I run it in the python dialog, it works as intended and when I run the tool Euclidean Distance tool it works normally.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on? relevant code below.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

lines = r"C:\shapes\Lines.shp
output = r"C:\rasters\EucDistLines.tif"

EucDist = arcpy.sa.EucDistance(lines, 6000, 3, output)
```

Comment: Edit your question to show what the parameters are, as the code looks OK to me which suggests its the inputs that may be odd?

Comment: Discovered that it was functioning correction. I just needed to do a EucDist.save to get the final file saved as the output for some reason is the intermediary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requires EucDist.save(output) after process. Otherwise, the output is Intermediary files.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

lines = r"C:\shapes\Lines.shp"
output = r"C:\rasters\EucDistLines.tif"

EucDist = arcpy.sa.EucDistance(lines, 6000, 3, output)
EucDist.save(output)
```

Comment: the first call to output is the direction raster. This is an optional parameter and should not have the same name as the euclidian distance.